# Extracting fields with REGEX from group of words with hypen and separated by dot

Tags: regex, rex

String Examples :

```
a1-a2.b1-b2-b3.c1-c2
```

Need to extract fields like :

```
a1-a2
b1-b2-b3 
c1-c2
```

group of words with hypen and separated by dot

Comment: Try  `[^\.]*` and match all occurrences with `g` modifier:  https://regex101.com/r/iL5jK6/1

Comment: Yeah, thanks trincot. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: OK, I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Could you accept the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
 [^\.]*
```

and match all occurrences with the `g` modifier.

[Regex tester](http://regex101.com/r/iL5jK6/1)